# Bitcoind doesn't add miner fee

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, confirmations, sending, bitcoin.conf

How do I make sure bitcoind's RPC call sendtoaddress adds miner fees to transactions?

Tried adding to our bitcoin.conf file:
mintxfee=0.0001

But some of the transactions still won't get any miner fee attached, causing payments to take hours or days to get confirmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct configuration parameter is: `paytxfee=<amount>`, where `<amount>`is the amount (fee) per kB to add to your outgoing txs